# WebStorm - Unwrap text in quotes

Tags: webstorm

Is there a way to unwrap text in quotes?

I'm looking for something like this:

`'my_var'` -> some shortcut -> `my_var`

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature; please vote for [WEB-15268](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15268) to be notified on any progress with it